# Trigger on User

Tags: trigger, user

I'm trying to change a Users ProfileId after the login.
I am able to [switch the profile](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a2fJWeJscps) but I like to do the callout from a Trigger.

```
trigger UserUpdateLastLogin on User (after update) {

    for(User updatedUser: Trigger.new){
        User oldUser = Trigger.oldMap.get(updatedUser.Id);
        if (updatedUser.LastLoginDate != oldUser.LastLoginDate) {
            UserProfileSwitcher.doSwitch();
        }
    }
}
```

Not even a Trigger Debug Log appears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a User logs in, that event does not invoke the User trigger. Here's a [similar question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/execute-an-action-run-a-trigger-every-time-a-user-logs-in-to-salesforce) that was asked earlier.

You have the option of embedding some code in the sidebar, or maybe have a very frequently running batch job which scans the User records for LastLogin since it last ran and then switches the Profile to the desired value.