# Creating a report on users using mobiles platforms by month

Tags: salesforce1-app, reporting, custom-report-type

I want to create a report on users who use salesforce through ipad and mobile. is it possible to do this ?

Comment: I think this issue lay be similar to this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/13456/trigger-on-user

And this: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/execute-an-action-run-a-trigger-every-time-a-user-logs-in-to-salesforce

Comment: @riadh i want to create a report not trigger

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to mention the goal of the trick, sorry: if you can count the users who connect from mobile with Trigger/Apex, you can store that data in a custom object and report on it. But one thing is sure: you have to use code to achieve what you want, because Salesforce does not offer an out-of-the-box tool for that. Report offers simple filters, and there is no filter that allows to detect if the a user is a mobile user or a desktop user.