# How to sync records at start of session only?

Tags: apex, visualforce, session, quickbooks

I'm working on a Salesforce/Quickbooks integration for a Force.com application. I need for the app to autosync during the user's initial login to the customer portal. Throughout the session, the sync will be on-demand, triggered by changes to the database (insert, update, or delete operations) for relevant objects. The on-demand sync is straightforward. However, I'm having difficulty finding a way to automatically start the sync at the beginning of the session.

We're using custom visualforce pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: This thread help any? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/execute-an-action-run-a-trigger-every-time-a-user-logs-in-to-salesforce

Comment: @geeljire 


plz tell me the process of authorization for quickbook to salesforce integration by code example i'm facing problem when authenticating.

Comment: @Aisha I'm not sure I follow your request, developer.intuit.com and the sfdc oauth playground should come in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting creative, (thanks, [@brianpeddle](https://twitter.com/brianpeddle/status/360810651884597249)!), you could add a Visualforce page as a sidebar component, or set it as the default page for the default app - see this question and its answer: [Execute an action / run a trigger every time a User logs in to Salesforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/9926/67).

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can launch a trigger based on somebody logging in so that means you'll need to use your controller to launch the sync. How about using a session cookie/variable for initial syncing? If the cookie indicates the initial sync has not happened then the controller launches the sync and updates the cookie. Otherwise the syncing only happens on-demand.

Comment: Thanks Mike. If I could choose two good answers, I would. As it is, using a redirecting VF page is better for my needs, although each technique has its limitations.