# Checkbox formula field based on User login status?

Tags: formula-field, login, checkbox

Can we have a checkbox that gets checked whenever a user logs-in and uncheck immediately after logout?

Use case I am trying to solve:
There are 12 Super users who will be accessing/maintaining the Salesforce Application. They work in shifts(Four users per 8 hours in a day) making it complete 24/7. As the part of their work, they receive notification emails from the end users(from Community). I wanted to restrict receiving emails whenever a Super user logs out, meaning, only logged in Super users should receive notification emails.

Note: Any Super user can be in any shift.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Not sure if this is still valid https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/execute-an-action-run-a-trigger-every-time-a-user-logs-in-to-salesforce

Comment: Why do you want this? What is are you trying to do? This may be an [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info). If you did any searches here, you probably would have seen there's no reliable way to prove a user is currently logged in conclusively (because, for example, they may have closed their browser but their session is still active in the session table). Either this is a duplicate question, or there may be something we can do to help you. Consider making an **[edit]** to your question.

Comment: @sfdcfox Please take a look at my edited version.

Comment: It seems like the simpler option would be to make them a shared mailbox and have the emails go there.