# How to query LoginHistory for Users Consecutively Logged for N Days

Tags: soql, login-history

I'm having trouble coming up with a design solution on how to retrieve users that have been logged into the system for 5 days straight.

By 5 days straight, I mean that they at least logged into the system once per day.

For the values that I need to query from the LoginHistory object, I need to get the LoginTime and UserId of the LoginHistory and from there, determine which user was logged into the system for 5 straight days.

Is there any way to retrieve the userId for users logged in for 5 days straight through SOQL? OR do I need to sort them out via Apex code?

```
SELECT Id,LoginTime,LoginType,Status,UserId FROM LoginHistory WHERE ???
```

What should be placed on the where clause?

I'm fine if this behavior is done in Apex but I'm at a loss as of now of such a design.

Any help is gladly accepted. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you should think out of the box and record users' successive connexion days when he logs in with a map containing the day and whether he logged in or not. Workaround trigger user login : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/execute-an-action-run-a-trigger-every-time-a-user-logs-in-to-salesforce. That way, you won't need to query and analyze the login history. If you really need to keep a history, you can create a small custom object that will contain for each week whether he logged in or not.

Comment: Did you have a look at the Adoption Dashboard app on appexchange? https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000004gHhLEAU